# If we give a small perturbation of matrix coefficient, can we find a corresponding solution which has small change w.r.t. the original one?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, computational-mathematics

> > Assume $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, $m<n$, and $\operatorname{rank}(A)<m$. For $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, assume $AX=b$ has a solution $X=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, then clearly there exist infinitely many solutions. By the structure of the solutions, we may assume $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$. Now my question is, for any $\epsilon>0$, does there exist $m \times n$ matrix $\tilde{A}$ with $\operatorname{rank}(\tilde{A})=m$ and vector $\tilde{X}=(\tilde{x}_1, \ldots, \tilde{x}_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|A-\tilde{A}\|<\epsilon, \|X-\tilde{X}\|<\epsilon$ and $\tilde{A} \tilde{X}=b$ ?

The question is a continuation of the question in the link
[How to find a perturbation of coefficients of a linear system to guarantee the error of solutions is small?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878674/how-to-find-a-perturbation-of-coefficients-of-a-linear-system-to-guarantee-the-e), which deals with the case $m=n$. Actually when $m=n$, the answer is negative, since if $b=0$, then $\tilde{X}=0$, which cannot satisfy $\|X-\tilde{X}\|<\epsilon$.

However, I do believe the answer is positive for the case $m<n$, but I've no idea how to give a proof. Maybe there are still counterexamples. Can anyone give me any ideas?

Comment: For a square system $AX=B$ (it is not the case here), if the ["condition number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of matrix A is very high, a very small perturbation of $A$ can yield a very large variation in the solution $X$ of this system. I imagine that for a (special) overdetermined system as is the case in this question, the "condition number" of some submatrix will appear as the keypoint to an answer.

Comment: The answer would become obvious if you consider the singular value decomposition of $A$.

Comment: If $m < n$, there's no $m \times n$ matrix with rank $n$.

Comment: Did you really mean $m <n$?

Comment: Sorry I messed up with my post. I made a typo about row and column. I've fixed them.

Comment: @user1551, Thank you so much! I've figured out the idea of proving the claim.